# Pandas date_parser function for year:doy:sod format

Tags: python, csv, pandas, datetime

I have a table in which the date and time is given in the format `year:day_of_year:seconds_of_day` (2nd column). A sample file may be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ojsevdn7skho9cm/sample.txt)

```
ABCD 15:010:00000 2564.6   4.0  -0.380  0.417  -1.313  0.520
ABCD 15:010:00300 2564.3   3.7  -0.389  0.396  -1.318  0.503
ABCD 15:010:00600 2563.9   3.5  -0.397  0.389  -1.324  0.496
ABCD 15:010:00900 2563.9   3.3  -0.411  0.368  -1.322  0.476
ABCD 15:010:01200 2563.8   3.0  -0.425  0.361  -1.320  0.466
ABCD 15:010:01500 2563.9   2.8  -0.432  0.340  -1.312  0.447
ABCD 15:010:01800 2564.3   2.6  -0.439  0.334  -1.304  0.439
```

I use pandas package to put the above table in a `pandas.DataFrame`:

```
names=['Site', 'Epoch', 'TroTot', 'Stdev','TgnTot', 'TgnStd', 'TgeTot', 'TgeStd']
parser = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%y:%j:%???')
df = pd.read_csv([FILE][1], 
                 header=None,
                 names=names,
                 delim_whitespace=True,
                 parse_dates=['Epoch'],
                 date_parser=parser)
```

I looked at the documentation but it seems to me that there is no format for the seconds of day. How could I change the parser function to work properly with this format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can first read your CSV file as it is (not parsing dates):

```
In [207]: df = pd.read_csv(fn, delim_whitespace=True, header=None, names=names)

In [208]: df
Out[208]:
     Site         Epoch  TroTot  Stdev  TgnTot  TgnStd  TgeTot  TgeStd
0    ABCD  15:010:00000  2564.6    4.0  -0.380   0.417  -1.313   0.520
1    ABCD  15:010:00300  2564.3    3.7  -0.389   0.396  -1.318   0.503
2    ABCD  15:010:00600  2563.9    3.5  -0.397   0.389  -1.324   0.496
3    ABCD  15:010:00900  2563.9    3.3  -0.411   0.368  -1.322   0.476
4    ABCD  15:010:01200  2563.8    3.0  -0.425   0.361  -1.320   0.466
5    ABCD  15:010:01500  2563.9    2.8  -0.432   0.340  -1.312   0.447
6    ABCD  15:010:01800  2564.3    2.6  -0.439   0.334  -1.304   0.439
7    ABCD  15:010:02100  2564.5    2.5  -0.453   0.314  -1.302   0.423
8    ABCD  15:010:02400  2564.2    2.4  -0.467   0.309  -1.299   0.419
9    ABCD  15:010:02700  2563.7    2.3  -0.482   0.287  -1.305   0.404
..    ...           ...     ...    ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
278  ABCD  15:010:83400  2561.6    2.2   0.033   0.276  -0.894   0.416
279  ABCD  15:010:83700  2562.1    2.2   0.053   0.271  -0.897   0.418
280  ABCD  15:010:84000  2562.7    2.3   0.073   0.285  -0.899   0.431
281  ABCD  15:010:84300  2562.6    2.3   0.108   0.283  -0.869   0.431
282  ABCD  15:010:84600  2562.7    2.3   0.144   0.299  -0.839   0.442
283  ABCD  15:010:84900  2562.4    2.3   0.175   0.298  -0.824   0.441
284  ABCD  15:010:85200  2562.4    2.3   0.207   0.313  -0.810   0.450
285  ABCD  15:010:85500  2562.1    2.3   0.228   0.314  -0.805   0.453
286  ABCD  15:010:85800  2562.2    2.5   0.249   0.331  -0.801   0.467
287  ABCD  15:010:86100  2562.6    2.7   0.253   0.337  -0.796   0.473

[288 rows x 8 columns]
```

now you can parse `Epoch` as follows:

```
In [209]: df['Epoch'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Epoch'].str[:6], format='%y:%j') + \
     ...:               pd.to_timedelta(df['Epoch'].str[7:].astype(int), unit='s')
     ...:

In [210]: df
Out[210]:
     Site               Epoch  TroTot  Stdev  TgnTot  TgnStd  TgeTot  TgeStd
0    ABCD 2015-01-10 00:00:00  2564.6    4.0  -0.380   0.417  -1.313   0.520
1    ABCD 2015-01-10 00:05:00  2564.3    3.7  -0.389   0.396  -1.318   0.503
2    ABCD 2015-01-10 00:10:00  2563.9    3.5  -0.397   0.389  -1.324   0.496
3    ABCD 2015-01-10 00:15:00  2563.9    3.3  -0.411   0.368  -1.322   0.476
4    ABCD 2015-01-10 00:20:00  2563.8    3.0  -0.425   0.361  -1.320   0.466
5    ABCD 2015-01-10 00:25:00  2563.9    2.8  -0.432   0.340  -1.312   0.447
6    ABCD 2015-01-10 00:30:00  2564.3    2.6  -0.439   0.334  -1.304   0.439
7    ABCD 2015-01-10 00:35:00  2564.5    2.5  -0.453   0.314  -1.302   0.423
8    ABCD 2015-01-10 00:40:00  2564.2    2.4  -0.467   0.309  -1.299   0.419
9    ABCD 2015-01-10 00:45:00  2563.7    2.3  -0.482   0.287  -1.305   0.404
..    ...                 ...     ...    ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
278  ABCD 2015-01-10 23:10:00  2561.6    2.2   0.033   0.276  -0.894   0.416
279  ABCD 2015-01-10 23:15:00  2562.1    2.2   0.053   0.271  -0.897   0.418
280  ABCD 2015-01-10 23:20:00  2562.7    2.3   0.073   0.285  -0.899   0.431
281  ABCD 2015-01-10 23:25:00  2562.6    2.3   0.108   0.283  -0.869   0.431
282  ABCD 2015-01-10 23:30:00  2562.7    2.3   0.144   0.299  -0.839   0.442
283  ABCD 2015-01-10 23:35:00  2562.4    2.3   0.175   0.298  -0.824   0.441
284  ABCD 2015-01-10 23:40:00  2562.4    2.3   0.207   0.313  -0.810   0.450
285  ABCD 2015-01-10 23:45:00  2562.1    2.3   0.228   0.314  -0.805   0.453
286  ABCD 2015-01-10 23:50:00  2562.2    2.5   0.249   0.331  -0.801   0.467
287  ABCD 2015-01-10 23:55:00  2562.6    2.7   0.253   0.337  -0.796   0.473

[288 rows x 8 columns]
```

check:

```
In [211]: df.dtypes
Out[211]:
Site              object
Epoch     datetime64[ns]
TroTot           float64
Stdev            float64
TgnTot           float64
TgnStd           float64
TgeTot           float64
TgeStd           float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Wonderful and impressively fast! ... Also many thanks for showing how to use timedelta.

Comment: FYI you don't need the astype in to_timedelta

Comment: @Jeff, thank you for the hint, but it gives me different result - it ignores then `unit='s'` parameter. Docstring says: `denote the unit, which is an integer/float number`

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/12136 yeah this is an open bug - pr to fix always welcome!

Answer (score 1):

For your data format, it is easiest to add the seconds to the date.  To pass a parser for your date format to `pandas.read_csv()` you can use something like:

**Code:**

```
import datetime as dt
def date_parser(date_string):
    date = dt.datetime.strptime(date_string[:6], '%y:%j')
    seconds = dt.timedelta(seconds=int(date_string[7:]))
    return date + seconds
```

**Test Code:**

```
from io import StringIO

data = u"""
ABCD 15:010:00000 2564.6   4.0  -0.380  0.417  -1.313  0.520
ABCD 15:010:00300 2564.3   3.7  -0.389  0.396  -1.318  0.503
ABCD 15:010:00600 2563.9   3.5  -0.397  0.389  -1.324  0.496
ABCD 15:010:00900 2563.9   3.3  -0.411  0.368  -1.322  0.476
ABCD 15:010:01200 2563.8   3.0  -0.425  0.361  -1.320  0.466
ABCD 15:010:01500 2563.9   2.8  -0.432  0.340  -1.312  0.447
ABCD 15:010:01800 2564.3   2.6  -0.439  0.334  -1.304  0.439
"""

names=['Site', 'Epoch', 'TroTot', 'Stdev',
       'TgnTot', 'TgnStd', 'TgeTot', 'TgeStd']

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data),
                 header=None,
                 names=names,
                 delim_whitespace=True,
                 parse_dates=['Epoch'],
                 date_parser=date_parser)
print(df)
```

**Results:**

```
   Site               Epoch  TroTot  Stdev  TgnTot  TgnStd  TgeTot  TgeStd
0  ABCD 2015-01-10 00:00:00  2564.6    4.0  -0.380   0.417  -1.313   0.520
1  ABCD 2015-01-10 00:05:00  2564.3    3.7  -0.389   0.396  -1.318   0.503
2  ABCD 2015-01-10 00:10:00  2563.9    3.5  -0.397   0.389  -1.324   0.496
3  ABCD 2015-01-10 00:15:00  2563.9    3.3  -0.411   0.368  -1.322   0.476
4  ABCD 2015-01-10 00:20:00  2563.8    3.0  -0.425   0.361  -1.320   0.466
5  ABCD 2015-01-10 00:25:00  2563.9    2.8  -0.432   0.340  -1.312   0.447
6  ABCD 2015-01-10 00:30:00  2564.3    2.6  -0.439   0.334  -1.304   0.439
```